Handling Deprecated AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter in Spring Security OAuth
I'm currently working on implementing an Authorization Server using Spring Security OAuth. While configuring the OAuth server, I've encountered that the AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter class itself has been deprecated.
Here's a segment of the code where I extend AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter:
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
protected static class OAuthConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter{
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private WebAdminCredentials webadminCredentials;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints)
            throws Exception {
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager).allowedTokenEndpointRequestMethods(HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.POST);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security)
            throws Exception {
        super.configure(security);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        // Configure clients
    }
}

Considering the deprecation of AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter, I have a couple of questions:
What alternatives are available for AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter?
How can I migrate my current implementation to accommodate the deprecation?
I couldn't find any suitable replacement code for this anywhere.

spring-security-oauth2 is end of life since 2022, last version was 2.5.x. There is a new Spring Authoritation sever project, which you can use.

https://spring.io/projects/spring-authorization-server

Thank you for letting me know. Is there any alternative approach for Spring Boot 2.7 version? Would it be better to upgrade to 3.0 instead?

Sure, it is better to update to Spring Boot 3.x, because Spring Boot 2.7 is out maintance since last september.
